# Change the default shell to Python

Tags: shell, python

If I changed my default shell from BASH to Python3 or IPython, would my Linux system have issues or produce errors?

Comment: Tangentially, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637668/why-are-scripting-languages-e-g-perl-python-ruby-not-suitable-as-shell-lang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it here (on a new user account) with IPython and, from limited testing, saw no problems.

You will want to run IPython using the `pysh` profile and the `--no-confirm-exit` parameter.