# Alternative shells (Javascript, Ruby, etc)?

Tags: shell, ruby, javascript

Does anyone use a shell written in Javascript, Ruby, Clojure, etc as their everyday unix shell, instead of bash, zsh, etc? Is there any reason not to?

Comment: @terdon I think you might want to reconsider "all that would do"

Comment: Also, this is the third or fourth time I ask you to go and accept some of the answers you have received. If you don't want to play by the rules of the site, why should we waste our time helping you?

Comment: themirror - As @terdon has mentioned it's helpful if you mark answers as the accepted ones mainly to let everyone on the site know that your question has been answered to your satisfaction, otherwise others might continue to spend their valuable time trying to provide additional answers when none are required.

Comment: Also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58011/is-there-a-javascript-shell?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `ipython` as a Python shell. It works, as I reported [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81161/change-the-default-shell-to-python).

But you might want to read [this answer on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640403/1071869) SO as for why Python, Ruby etc... won't make good languages for a shell.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine used to have `emacs` as it's default shell. :)

Other people like `screen` as a login shell for remote systems.

You can even use plain `irb` as a shell. (There is a [module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166347/how-do-i-use-ruby-for-shell-scripting) for adding the basic shell commands as ruby methods.)